# ambiguous object of prepositional phrase?

Tags: meaning, prepositional-objects

What is the object of the prepositional phrase `along with...` in this sentence, `I was in the first wave of implementation, along with eighteen million other vampires, witches, ghouls, werewolves, feral youth, and the like.`

Is the object all the things together or each thing individually.

In other words, are there eighteen million ghouls or are there eighteen million creatures altogether?

Comment: *Syntactically,* it's ambiguous, but *pragmatically* no-one would be likely to assume 18M of each of the named "other" types for this *exact* text. But if we replaced adjectival ***eighteen million other*** with a different term (such as ***unemployed*** or ***British***), you could make valid cases for interpreting the adjectival element as applying to either ***all*** of the following elements, or just the first one. It's hard to imagine a context where it could apply to, for example, only the first ***two*** following elements - but again, I think that's just pragmatics, not "syntax rules".

Comment: (Either ***all*** collectively, or ***each*** separately, I mean.)

Comment: The complement of "with" is the entire sequence following it. The salient interpretation of the determiner phrase "eighteen million" is that it relates to all the items in aggregate. The individual items form a coordination of noun phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you substitute "wave of implementation" with "Group" then you can see that the preposition refers to that group. This group is the 18 million.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take a look around and check out the guideline for [how to write a good answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Could you add some clarification or elaboration to your answer? It doesn't appear to actually answer the question. The OP wants to know the population of the wave/group.